# Why does this for in loop hide the last li element added via js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to learn JS Dom Manipulation, and while tinkering along the code,
I learnt that the "for in" loop is hiding the last li element "Zathura" (before creation. But the traditional "for" loop doesn't do that,
can someone explain what is happening?

1. This is how the page looks like without any loop, Zathura is added with JS.

[image: No loop]

2. This is traditional for loop and that's what I wanted with the below for in.

[image: List item]

3. But this is what I get when I run the for in, Zathura goes away.

[image: for in loop]

4. Adding the for in to the bottom of the Zathura creation fixes it, can someone explain what's happening?

[image: for in bottom]

5.Whole code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .licolor{
            color: blue;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
    </style>
    <title>ManipulatingDom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Fav Movies</h1>
        <ul>
            <li class="list">Harry Potter</li>
            <li class="list">John wick</li>
            <li class="list">Interstellar</li>
            <li class="list">Wolverine</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script defer>
    // DOM MANIPULATION

    // STYLING ELEMENTS
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
    // Traditional for loop works fine, this is what I'm trying to achieve with the for in below.
    // for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    //     list[i].style.color='blue';
    //     list[i].style.fontSize='1.5rem'
    // }

    // for..in.. this hides the last li which i'm adding by js, why though?
    for(let each in list){
        list[each].style.color='blue';
        list[each].style.fontSize='1.5rem';
    }


    // CREATING Last LI ELEMENT
    const ul= document.querySelector('ul');
    const li= document.createElement('li');
    ul.append(li);

    li.innerText = 'Zathura';
    li.classList.add('licolor');
    
    // this fixes it, but is it hoisting issue or something can someone explain why above traditional for loop is working properly and not for in, and here it works fine.
    // for(let each in list){
    //     list[each].style.color='blue';
    //     list[each].style.fontSize='1.5rem';
    // }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remember to check your console for errors before posting questions. An error gets thrown, so the code below it (including the part that adds the new `<li>`) doesn't run. `for..in` iterates over many properties that aren't numeric indicies (and for those, `list[each]` does not refer to an HTMLElement, so assigning to a property of `style` throws)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I understood what was happening, and I will remember to check my console every time when something is not working properly.

Comment: [Difference between for...of and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#difference_between_for...of_and_for...in)